# Removing data frames from a list that contains a certain value under a variable in R

Tags: r, correlation

Currently have a list of 27 correlation matrices with 7 variables, doing social science research.

Some correlations are "NA" due to missing data.

When I do the analysis, however, I do not analyse all variables in one go.

In a particular instance, I would like to keep one of the variables conditionally, if it contains at least some value (i.e. other than "NA", since there are 7 variables, I am keeping anything that DOES NOT contain 6"NA"s, and correlation with itself, 1 -> this is the tricky part because 1 is a value, but it's meaningless to me in a correlation matrix).

Appreciate if anyone could enlighten me regarding the code.

I am rather new to R, and the only thought I have is to use an if statement to set the condition. But I have been trying for hours but to no avail, as this is my first real coding experience.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is wrong with reporting a summary of `NA`?  I think this is potentially useful information and might be preferable to a predictor/variable disappearing entirely from the report.

Comment: Show us some of your coding work that you have done so far. ?

Answer (score 0):

since you didn't provide sample data, I am first going to convert your matrix into a dataframe and then I am just going to pretend that you want us to see if your dataframe `df` has a variable `var` with at least one non-NA or 1. value

`df <- as.data.frame(as.table(matrix))` should convert your matrix into a dataframe

`table(df$var)` will show you the distribution of values in your dataframe's variable. from here you can make your judgement call on whether to keep the variable or not.